# How to have a thorough horizontal line in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, rules

I want the horizontal lines to go across the second column; form start to the end of the second column. I found some suggestions to make a nested table, But couldn't understand those.
This my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
        a & \begin{tabular}{c | c}
            angel & value
        \end{tabular} & Overshoot  & Settling time & Rise time                  \tabularnewline\hline
        Case i
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}}
            $\theta_i$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
            \end{tabular}
            \tabularnewline\hline   
            $\theta_f$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                30 \\ 30 \\ 30 \\ 30
            \end{tabular}
            %               \tabularnewline\hline
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        \tabularnewline\hline
        Case ii
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}}
            $\theta_i$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                30 \\ 30 \\ 30 \\ 30
            \end{tabular}
            \tabularnewline\hline
            $\theta_f$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                60 \\ 60 \\ 60 \\ 60
            \end{tabular}
            %               \tabularnewline\hline
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\

        \end{tabular}
        \tabularnewline\hline
        Case iii
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}}
            $\theta_i$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                90 \\ 60 \\ 45 \\ 75
            \end{tabular}
            \tabularnewline\hline
            $\theta_f$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                120 \\ 90 \\ 105 \\ 135
            \end{tabular}
            %           \tabularnewline\hline
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        \tabularnewline\hline
        Case iv
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c|@{}c@{}}
            $\theta_i$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                120 \\ 90 \\ 105 \\ 135
            \end{tabular}
            \tabularnewline\hline 
            $\theta_f$ &    \begin{tabular}{c}
                150 \\ 120 \\ 135 \\ 165
            \end{tabular}
            %           \tabularnewline\hline
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
            1  \\ 
            1  \\
        \end{tabular}
        \tabularnewline\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why many tabular enviroments?

Comment: why have you tagged this with biblatex or pdftex or tex-core?

Comment: I'm just beginner.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the `multirow` package in combination with the `\cmidrule{}` command:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
        \toprule
        a & angle & value & Overshoot & Settling time & Rise time \\ \midrule
        \multirow{8}{*}{Case i} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_i$} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
        {} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_f$} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \midrule
        \multirow{8}{*}{Case ii} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_i$} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
        {} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_f$} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \midrule
        \multirow{8}{*}{Case iii} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_i$} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 90 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 90 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 90 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
        {} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_f$} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \midrule
        \multirow{8}{*}{Case iv} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_i$} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
        {} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_f$} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        {} & {} & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Vertical lines in LaTeX tables usually do not look great, so if at all possible do not use them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a starting point for you to work on. I removed the vertical rules, and used the command `\cmidrule{2-6}` for drawing custom horizontal ones.

`\toprule` and `\bottomrule` appear before and after the table respectively, while the full horizontal ones are done with `\midrule`.

[image: table figure]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \toprule
    a & angel & value & Overshoot & Settling time & Rise time \\ 
    \midrule
    \multirow{8}{*}{Case i} & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_i$}   & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            &                               & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            &                               & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            &                               & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
                            & \multirow{4}{*}{$\theta_f$}   & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            &                               & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            &                               & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                            &                               & 30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \midrule
                            &                               & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
                            &                               & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
                            &                               & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
                            &                               & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
    \bottomrule                 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a simpler code with the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setcellgapes{2pt}

\begin{document}

\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & angel & value & Overshoot & Settling time & Rise time \tabularnewline\hline
    \multirowcell{5}{Case i}
    & $\theta_i$ & \makecell{0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0}%\\
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    \tabularnewline\cline{2-3}
    & $\theta_f$ & \makecell{30 \\ 30 \\ 30 \\ 30}
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%
    \tabularnewline\hline
    \multirowcell{5}{Case ii}
    & $\theta_i$ & \makecell{30 \\ 30 \\ 30 \\ 30}%\\
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    \tabularnewline\cline{2-3}
    & $\theta_f$ & \makecell{60 \\ 60 \\ 60 \\ 60}
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%
    \tabularnewline\hline
    \multirowcell{5}{Case iii}
    & $\theta_i$ & \makecell{90 \\ 60 \\ 45 \\ 75}%\\
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    \tabularnewline\cline{2-3}
    & $\theta_f$ & \makecell{120 \\ 90 \\ 105 \\ 135}
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%
    \tabularnewline\hline
    \multirowcell{5}{Case iv}
    & $\theta_i$ & \makecell{90 \\ 60 \\ 45 \\ 75}%\\
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}% \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}
    \tabularnewline\cline{2-3}
    & $\theta_f$ & \makecell{150 \\ 120 \\ 135 \\ 165}
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%&
     & \makecell{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1}%
    \tabularnewline\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the most expressive way of writing this table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[1.5]\centering
\caption{Overshoot, settling time, and rise time for different values of $\theta_{i}$ and $\theta_f$ in four cases}
\begin{tabular}{*8{c}}\toprule
                        &&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Angle}& & & \\ \cmidrule{3-4}
Case                    && $\theta_{i}$& $\theta_{f}$& & Overshoot & Settling time & Rise time\\ \cmidrule {1-1} \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{6-8}
\multirow{4}{*}{I}      &&  0   &   30      &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  0   &   30      &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  0   &   30      &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  0   &   30      &&1 &1 &1 \\ \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{II}     &&  30  &   60      &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  30  &   60      &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  30  &   60      &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  30  &   60      &&1 &1 &1 \\ \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{III}    &&  90  &   120     &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  60  &   90      &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  45  &   105     &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  65  &   135     &&1 &1 &1 \\ \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{IV}     &&  120 &   150     &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  90  &   120     &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  105 &   135     &&1 &1 &1 \\
                        &&  135 &   165     &&1 &1 &1 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to be losing a large amount of detail in this type of table, since you're combining the two different angles in one row/entry. I'm pretty sure the use of `1` in the table was just an example...

Comment: @Werner  May be you are right! but the OP should have been more explicit about this. Besides, for `\theta_{i}` and `\theta_{f}`, are they combinations or single instances? this what actually leads to ambiguity. In my case I assumed the former.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should put `$\theta_i$` and `$\theta_f$` in  parallel , not in series, but I thinking of page limitations.

Comment: @AlFagera Updated my answer.

Comment: @ AboAmmar I was really wondering, but not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) (you included it, but never used its capabilities) and [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for horizontal alignment of integers in a table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c S[table-format=3] c c c}
  \toprule
  Case & Angle & {Value} & Overshoot & Settling time & Rise time \\
  \midrule
  I   & $\theta_i$ &   0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &   0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &   0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &   0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      \cmidrule{2-6}
      & $\theta_f$ &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \midrule
  II  & $\theta_i$ &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  30 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      \cmidrule{2-6}
      & $\theta_f$ &  60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \midrule
  III & $\theta_i$ &  90 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  60 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  45 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  75 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      \cmidrule{2-6}
      & $\theta_f$ & 120 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  90 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            & 105 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            & 135 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \midrule
  IV  & $\theta_i$ & 120 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            &  90 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            & 105 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            & 135 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      \cmidrule{2-6}
      & $\theta_f$ & 150 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            & 120 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            & 135 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      &            & 165 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The use of [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) is not really necessary, if a proper display is used.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions, I would really vote up all of them, but for my reputation limitations, I couldn't.

Comment: @AlFagera It would be helpful, however, if you could mark one of the above answers as accepted, if you think it answered your question. That way the question is marked accordingly.